# ext3 Snapshot Support

Tags: lvm, ext3, snapshot

Does the ext3 filesystem support snapshotting?  If so, is can this be done with straight partitions with no LVM?

An example of "straight partitions" would be the following:

1. /dev/sda1 /boot ext3
2. /dev/sda2 /     ext3
3. /dev/sda3       swap

Comment: Ooooh I want to do this too. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
Unlike a number of modern file systems, Ext3 does not have native support for
snapshots - the ability to quickly capture the state of the filesystem at
arbitrary times, instead relying on less space-efficient volume level snapshots
provided by the Linux LVM. The Next3 file system is a modified version of Ext3
which offers snapshots support, yet retains compatibility to the EXT3 on-disk
format
```

Citation:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3#Lack_of_snapshots_support

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [R1Soft Hot Copy](http://www.r1soft.com/free-tool-linux-hot-copy) for taking a point-in-time snapshot of a filesystem. Using this, you can take a clean snapshot without using LVM. It's pretty clean and should give you what you're asking for.

Comment: That looks pretty neat, I'll have to try that out.